# Python - ETree element.find on a partial match

Tags: python, elementtree

the below code snippet loops through a few xml files and pulls 3 "columns" in a dictionary from each.  One of the xmls has first field named slightly different "IndexName" not "IndexID".  how to do i get away with a single field list such as

```
field_list = ['Index*', 'CompositeSpread', 'CompositePrice',]
```

to find a partial match:

```
strXpath = "./row"

field_list = ['IndexID', 'CompositeSpread', 'CompositePrice',]
field_list1 = ['IndexName', 'CompositeSpread', 'CompositePrice',]

tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()

value_list = []
for el in root.findall(strXpath):
    value_list.append([el.find(x).text for x in field_list])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i came up with was using both `'IndexID'` and `'IndexName'` fields in the `field_list` and checking `if el.find(x) is not None` in the list comprehension:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    strXpath = "./row"

    field_list = ['IndexName', 'IndexID', 'CompositeSpread', 'CompositePrice',]

    tree = ET.parse(file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    value_list = []
    for el in root.findall(strXpath):
        value_list.append([el.find(x).text for x in field_list if el.find(x) is not None])
```

Comment: this will also work if you get both fields, unnecessary it will add both of them.

Comment: Agreed. Haven’t thought of it as these fields are mutually exclusive in my case as they stem from inconsistent naming convention for different files. But there is only one such field per xml file.